# remove duplicates from a cell VBA compile error

Tags: excel, compilation, duplicates, cell

*EDIT*  Is there something better / easier I could do to accomplish this?

I am stumped as to why a bit of code I have is coming up with the "Sub or Function not defined" compile error.

I have a bill of materials with duplicated references in cells in it,
e.g.: C1, C1, C1, C6, C6, C6
and I am trying to remove the duplicates but keep the unique references.

```
Sub ZapDuplicatesInPlace()
'
Dim r As Range, va() As Variant
Set r = Application.InputBox("Select range to remove duplicates cell by cell.", "Remove Duplicates From Lists", , , , , , 8)
va = r.Value
For i = LBound(va, 1) To UBound(va, 1)
    For j = LBound(va, 2) To UBound(va, 2)
        'This assumes delimiter is comma followed by space.
        va(i, j) = RemoveDuplicates(CStr(va(i, j)), ", ")
    Next j
Next i
'Print output to sheet
r.Value = va
End Sub
```

Comment: `RemoveDuplicates` is a method of the `Range` object, not an array (your syntax is off anyway).

Comment: I figured it was something with the syntax, but if there's any way I can correct this, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Could you store the address on the sheet and then use RD on the sheet? If not, you'd need a custom function or sub to store unique values and addresses in an output array.